# I can't access services on a separate vlan why not?

Tags: networking, cisco, router, switch, vlan

I have two cisco switches and a cisco router.  The  router connects to the first switch (A) and the second switch (B) is connected to switch A.  Switch A only has one vlan port set (The one that connects to switch B).  From a device connected to switch B I can access anything that is connected to switch A.  But from switch A I can not access devices that are connected to switch B.  Devices connected to Switch A and B can access things behind the router just fine.  What do I need to add to the router or switches to allow devices connected on switch A to access devices connected to switch B  ... some of the configuration follows to give more detail.....

> Switch A
>   Most ports are set as
>   interface FastEthernet0/2
>   no ip address
>   end
>
> The Port that connects to Switch B is set as
>   interface FastEthernet0/20
>   switchport access vlan 5
>   no ip address
>   end
>
> Switch A also has VLAN's Set
>
> interface Vlan1
>   ip address 192.168.2.10 255.255.255.0
>   end
>
> interface Vlan5
>   ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
>   end
>
> Switch B All ports are configured like the following
>   interface FastEthernet0/2
>   switchport access vlan 5
>   end
>
> The Router uses the folling route
>   ip route 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.10
>   And has an IP address of 192.168.2.1 (Putting it in the same subnet as switch A)
>
> The interface on the Router has the following config ...
>
> interface FastEthernet0/0
>   ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
>   no ip redirects
>   no ip unreachables
>   no ip proxy-arp
>   ip flow ingress
>   ip flow egress
>   ip nat inside
>   ip virtual-reassembly
>   no ip route-cache cef
>   ip route-cache flow
>   no ip mroute-cache
>   duplex auto
>   speed auto
>   no mop enabled
>   service-policy input LAN-EDGE
>   end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was something stupid ... I did not have a default gateway set on Switch B (Which has an IP address of 192.168.5.2) as soon as I set the ip default-gateway 192.168.5.1 everything worked great.